# How to add links to search results from Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a search bar which uses Ajax implementation to search my database and query the input data.[view of results generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KkSy.png) My question is how do I make the results show up as clickable link so that when clicked they go straight to the view which holds more information about them? I have added the code for database query and the script used for accessing the database based on what was entered by the user in the search box.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-data').unbind().keyup(function(e) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value.length>3) {
        //alert(99933);
        searchData(value);
      }
      else {
        $('#search-result-container').hide();
      }
    }
                                    );
  }
                   );
  function searchData(val){
    $('#search-result-container').show();
    $('#search-result-container').html('<div><img src="preloader.gif" width="50px;" height="50px"> <span style="font-size: 20px;">Searching...</span></div>');
    $.post('controller.php',{
      'search-data': val}
           , function(data){
      if(data != "")
        $('#search-result-container').html(data);
      else    
        $('#search-result-container').html("<div class='search-result'>No Result Found...</div>");
    }
          ).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      //any errors?

      alert("There was an error here!");
      //alert with HTTP error
    }
                );
  }
</script>

    <form>
<div class="manage-accounts" id="users">
      <div id="search-box-container" >
        <label > Search For Any Event: 
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input  type="text" id="search-data" name="searchData" placeholder="Search By Event Title (word length should be greater than 3) ..." autocomplete="off" />
      </div>
      <div id="search-result-container" style="border:solid 1px #BDC7D8;display:none; ">
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

database query:

```
 <?php
include("fetch.php");
class DOA{
public function dbConnect(){
$dbhost = DB_SERVER; // set the hostname
$dbname = DB_DATABASE ; // set the database name
$dbuser = DB_USERNAME ; // set the mysql username
$dbpass = DB_PASSWORD;  // set the mysql password
try {
$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass); 
$dbConnection->exec("set names utf8");
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $dbConnection;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}
public function searchData($searchVal){
try {
$dbConnection = $this->dbConnect();
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE title like :searchVal");
$val = "%$searchVal%"; 
$stmt->bindParam(':searchVal', $val , PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->execute();
$Count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
//echo " Total Records Count : $Count .<br>" ;
$result ="" ;
if ($Count  > 0){
while($data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {          
$result = $result .'<div class="search-result">'.$data['title'].'</div>';    
}
return $result ;
}
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. It would be **beneficial for you** to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Please read through that and you'll see how Stack Overflow works, *"learning the ropes"* as it were. It will give you a good idea on how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help you have a better and positive experience here, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: "how do I make the results show up as clickable link"...by outputting HTML which contains the relevant hyperlink. Without more detail, we can't really tell you more than that.

Comment: What did you receive from server? If you got the html, then the server will generate the links. If you receive only a json, then the JavaScript parser will do the job.

Comment: What I get is just the title of a certain event from the database table 'Events'

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems you're expecting ready-made content to come back. So I suggest you change your server-side code to output HTML which includes the relevant hyperlink. If you need help with that, you'll have to show the server code.

Comment: Thanks for the second update. You need to give us an example of the URL which would open the event in its own view. But the basic idea is going to be something like `$result = $result .'<div class="search-result"><a href="http://event.php?id='.$data["id"].'">'.$data['title'].'</a></div>';`. I made an assumption about your URL and about you having an ID for your event in a database field, but that's the general idea, you just write some extra HTML which creates a hyperlink.

Comment: that's really helpful because that's the idea behind it. here is a sample url for an event http://reslifeconnect.org/events.php?event=1068#.tabView

Comment: @ADyson Your response was perfect. I was able to modified your code and it worked well for me. Thank you very much

Comment: @TajhMcDonald that's great. I added it as a full answer, if you are able to mark it accepted - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is making the search result clickable and browser loads the hyperlink clicked on, just echo the hyperlink from your database or JSON file depends on where they are into the html anchor element such as this:

`<a href="<?php echo $row['page_link'] ?>"><?php echo $row['page_title'] ?></a>`

Note: I echoed the page link in the anchor `href` attribute, that should solve the problem.

Comment: where would you recommend I place this code? So my far my attempts cause the search process to crash?

Comment: In your php code that loops the result, if you may post your php script runs the code and I will highlight where you do just that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add some code to make a hyperlink into the HTML your PHP is generating:

```
$result = $result .'<div class="search-result"><a href="http://events.php?id='.$data["id"].'">'.$data['title'].'</a></div>';
```

I have made an assumption about the name of your ID field but you can see the pattern you need to use.